# EF Core - Creating two navigation properties mapped to a single inverse property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-core-2.1

I have the following entities set up.

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public HashSet<Wheel> FrontWheels { get; set; };
    public HashSet<Wheel> RearWheels { get; set; };
}

public class Wheel
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    //public Car Car { get; set; }
    public double Diameter { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
}
```

A Car has Wheels. It interacts with the fronts and rears very differently and therefore they are held in different collections.  A wheel by itself is neither a front or a rear (it could be either), it is only through its association with the car that it is given a position on the car.

I can set this up in EF Core 2.1 using the following config:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().HasMany(car => car.FrontWheels).WithOne();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().HasMany(car => car.RearWheels).WithOne();
```

This creates a Wheel table with two nullable fk columns, CarIdFrontWheel & CarIdRearWheel.  I understand why it creates two columns and why they're nullable (only 1 fk column will be populated for each Wheel row, and that column describes the position on the car).  This schema describes the situation and I am happy with that.

Now the problem starts when I want to add back in the commented out inverse navigation property - so that I can navigate from a Wheel to it's connected Car.  However I configure it, EF always wants to add another fk named CarId to the Wheel table to map back to a Car.  I understand why it needs to do this - Otherwise I'm attempting to ask one property (Wheel.Car) to partake in two relationships.  Both fks could point to a different Car id, etc.

However, what I am asking seems logically reasonable from an entity relationship point of view.  If we were writing this data access manually, we could make the schema work without this unnecessary (somewhat de-normalized) 3rd foreign key.

- Is this possible to configure these entities using just the two
  (CarIdFrontWheel & CarIdRearWheel) foreign keys?
- Should I instead just accept the existence of the CarId foreign key?
- Or, are there some changes I can make to my model to help this situation?

Comment: i would approach this slightly differently.  my gut feeling is that a wheel should have a fk field for WheelPostion (Front/Rear).  I would have `one` collection of Wheels / vehicle.  (You could implement a business rule to validate you have the number of wheels required and and the correct wheel types.)  just my 2 cents...

Comment: Btw I am aware of aggregates and acknowledge that in this situation it may seem like a Wheel shouldn't need to navigate back to its Car.  We have already considered this line of thought, but unfortunately in this case we really do need 2-way navigation of the properties.

Comment: the Wheel class can have a nav property back to a `Car` (CardId). And to determine which actual tyre the wheel is one may also imagine it having a `Position` Property (Front-Left) or similar...

Comment: EF (Core) requires (allows) one navigation property to be mapped to one and only one relationship. Starting from here, it's up to you what is acceptable - 2 or more FKs, or single collection with property (sort of a discriminator) at the many side. I would personally go the second way.

Comment: Thanks @JohnB I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "a fk field for WheelPostion (Front/Rear)".   I have thought a lot about creating just one collection of Wheels - but surely that would then require the Wheel class having some knowledge of where its installed?

Comment: Yes, a property of a wheel on a car can be thought of as having a position.  i see no major drama with that.  So it would be as complex as you want to go.  to see how deep you can go => https://schema.org/Car

Comment: @IvanStoev Is it possible to use a discriminator to describe (and map) which collection the many side should be mapped to?  Or do I need to bring that discriminator property through into code and do it manually?

Comment: also think about how developers will need to access data: eg `car.Wheels.Front();` or `car.Wheels.FrontLeft();`

Comment: @Martyn What I meant by discriminator was a enum or bool property mentioned by JonB. And **single** collection (if you read the start of my previous comment, **one** navigation property (collection or reference) == **one** relationship (FK)). You can't configure EF to populate two logical collections for you. It should be one collection. When you need to separate it, you (or the clients of your code) would  use simple LINQ `Where`.

Comment: Please note that while the 2 FK solution allows you to use 2 collections (mapped to 2 inverse reference navigation properties!), it introduces the so called *multiple cascade paths* issue, so you can't use cascade delete, and in general creates more problems than solving something.